# Connect Android device

Tags: android, samsung, phone

I've a phone with Android and I use Ubuntu in my PC. The thing is that I can connect my phone through USB and Ubuntu can read it, I mean, I can see the files and stuff, but that's it.

I can't transfer files without broking them, can't view photos either, and all the things that I can do with Windows are gone when using Ubuntu or any Linux distro.

Maybe I'm missing drivers, the phone is Samsung.

Can anyone help me?

I've search a lot but couldn't find a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: You could try the following link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/257874/ubuntu-cant-see-my-android-phone

Comment: Muhnamana That repo it's outdated, or at least it's not downloading files, with a 404 error.

Comment: I'll remove my link, sorry I probably copied an incorrect one.

Comment: This might help as well...http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/upgrade-to-gvfs-with-mtp-support-in.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get mtpfs package : `sudo apt-get install mtpfs`

Make sure to unlock your phone when connecting to PC

Then use it as follows :

- Create a directory to mount Android fs
- as user type : `mtpfs /path/to/mountpoint`

to unmount use `fusermount -u` command to unmount

This is for device fs access only, if you're looking for android tools (adb and fastboot) :

- install android-tools-adb and android-tools-fastboot :

`sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot`

Comment: That seems to be an option. I still can't see photos directly from the phone, but at least I can move them to my PC now.

Comment: Didn’t help me :/

Answer (score 0):

I have been using my Note 2 with KUbuntu for 2 years already. Sometimes it does not fire up on the first attempt and I have to reconnect  the wire. 
However, I think it is KDE achievement, not ubuntu system's. May be you switch to KDE? Many things work better there.
Anyway, here is a good workaround for you: if your linux PC is in the network with wi-fi router, you can install one of the numerous FTP servers or Samba servers on the phone and use FileZilla to access it. It always works flawlessly, and wireless too!
Same stands for Bluetooth, but is waaay slower.