# Ubuntu 13.10 Cannot Detect Galaxy S4

Tags: 13.10, android

Ubuntu won't recognize my S4 and on the phone it doesn't realize it's connected either, it just shows that it's charging.
I've read posts such as [Ubuntu can't see my Android phone!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257874/ubuntu-cant-see-my-android-phone) but that shouldn't be a problem as 13.10 supports MTP.

Any ideas as to what's going on?

It came up with "Couldn't find matching udev device" as an error one time, but I can't get it to show up again.

Also, I tried installing mtp-tools and restarting but that didn't work either.

Edit:
If you're going to downvote this could you at least comment why?

Comment: Install `mtp-tools` and then try to connect your pc.

Answer (score 0):

In your mobile device settings, check if it is set to "connect as media device". If it is set to "connect in camera mode", it will not be detected by Ubuntu.